# What kind of the validation is done by the $VALIDATE_PRODUCT flag in Build Options in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

In Xcode in "Build Settings" in "Build Options" we have a flag Boolean $VALIDATE_PRODUCT

I have found in documentation [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html) following description:

> Description: Specifies whether to run product-validation tests

What kind of validation is done when this flag is set to `true`?

Comment: good question... i'd also like to know